# How to print special characters in groovy

Tags: java, groovy

I want to print √ (\u221A) http://www.fileformat.info/info/unicode/char/221a/index.htm character in groovy

```
file = new File("log.txt")
if(!file.exists()){
    file.createNewFile()
}

file.withWriter('UTF-8'){
    file.write("\u221A √")
}
```

I get **3F** 20 **E2 3F 9A** in hex editor.

I don't know why this happens. In second case it looks similar to 0xE2 0x88 0x9A which is correct UTF-8 for that character.

I tried to run groovy with option -c UTF-8 but I get `3F 20 3F`

Comment: If I run that script, saved in UTF-8 format, the output is byte values `0xe2 0x88 0x9a 0x20 0xe2 0x88 0x9a` as expected.  What is the encoding of your source file?

Comment: I think the file is in UTF-8 the hex code of the source file where it matters is like this: file.append("\u221A â.š") / 66 69 6C 65 2E 61 70 70 65 6E 64 28 22 5C 75 32 32 31 41 20 **E2 88 9A** 22 29

Comment: I changed function from file.write to file.append but everything else remained the same

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It turns out that I needed

```
JAVA_TOOL_OPTIONS -Dfile.encoding=UTF8
```

in my Windows environment variables.

Answer (score 0):

For those who are dealing with this error working with Groovy scripts, and working with another console (such as Git Bash), change the variable name `JAVA_TOOL_OPTIONS` for `JAVA_OPTS`

```
export JAVA_OPTS=-Dfile.encoding=UTF-8
```